# Deskpins / Afloat Alternative Mac Mavericks

Tags: mac, window, osx-mavericks, pin, afloat

When I was on PC i loved deskpins.   Afloat is a similar app for mac.

I am having trouble getting the Github app to run after compiling and archiving with xCode. https://github.com/millenomi/afloat/

The only active download I could find for Afloat is here http://en.softonic.com/s/afloat:mac, but it doesn't seem to work with Mavericks.

I would think that there would be several alternatives, but apparently not.  http://alternativeto.net/software/deskpins/?platform=mac

Unfortunately, the only applications I can get Afloat to work with are finder and Safari.

Can anyone help me get a Afloat or an alternative working with Mavericks?

Comment: Afloat has started to work a little better for me.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/fjolnir/afloat

This version of Afloat builds fine on Mavericks, and even has an added option "focus follows mouse".

Answer (score 0):

Which features of Afloat do you use? or which features are you most interested in?  I'm not familiar with deskpins...

If you're interested in the drag-from-anywhere or resize-from-anywhere features of Afloat (the only features I, personally, ever used frequently), there is an alternative that I just stumbled across called [HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com) that seems to do what I want, and it is Mavericks-compatible.  It also has a few other features that might be useful, but I haven't really investigated them yet.  It's not free, but if it works well (I'm still testing it), it'll be well worth the $10 for me.

If you're interested in the keep-on-top feature of Afloat, I haven't found any alternatives for that yet.

Comment: I am very satisfied with Shift and also Better Touch tool for resizing and moving windows.  I am looking for keep on top.